How to get playwright page url
I am trying to get the current page url in python and playwright.
I have tried:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
   browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, channel='chrome')
   context = browser.new_context(accept_downloads=True)
   page = context.new_page()
   page.goto("https://google.com")
   page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
   pageurl = page.url()

last line gives error: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'str' object is not callable
What am I doing wrong?

This is a fairly common difference between the Node and Py playwright APIs. .first is another common property in Python that is often called as .first().

That's because url is not a function. You can just simply do:
pageurl = page.url
print(pageurl)


Thank you so much. I got that from googling it.

I meant I got the bad answer by googling it.
